# why Image is not loaded in pie 9 only Samsung Company mobile?

Tags: android

First time it  is not Show the Image after going to another activity and come back it will show the image .

```
Glide.with(viewHolder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(s)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .dontAnimate()
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(1000, 600))
                .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

This is my manifest File.

```
<application
        android:name=".egcashback.Bigwelt"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,UnusedAttribute"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".egcashback.AboutusActivity"
            android:label="About Us"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".egcashback.DirectOrderAct" />
```

This is my Network File

```
<network-security-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.freshcare.w4u.in</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

My Activity Code.

```
 public void getChallenge1() {
       splash.homeCategoryRecModelArrayList.clear();
        AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
//            requestParams.put("task", "GetXValues");
//            requestParams.put("random_number", jsonResponse1.get("random").toString());

        asyncHttpClient.get(Const.Base_Url + "manage/api/p_category/all/?X-Api-Key=" + Const.API_KEY + "&start=0&limit=9&field=shop_id&filter=" + Const.Shop_id + "&parent=0&loc_id=" + HomePage.loc_id, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                Log.v("allcategory", "statusCode " + statusCode);
                Log.v("allcategory", "responseString " + responseString);
            }


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
// If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("p_category");
                    splash.homeCategoryRecModelArrayList = Parser.parseHomeCategoryList(jsonArray);

                    setSlider();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v("mp3file", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }


        });


    }
```

My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sbg"
    tools:context=".egcashback.HomePage">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/sbg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchhome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/viewrounded"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filt"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Search For Products"
            android:padding="1dp" />







        <!--        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout-->
        <!--            android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"-->
        <!--            android:clickable="false"-->
        <!--            android:visibility="visible"-->
        <!--            android:layout_below="@id/searchhome"-->
        <!--            android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <!--
                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewcategoryhome"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                                android:background="@color/category"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                app:reverseLayout="false"
                                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager">

                            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                -->

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSlider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="none">



                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                            <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView
                                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="186dp"
                                app:sliderAnimationDuration="600"
                                app:sliderAutoCycleDirection="back_and_forth"
                                app:sliderAutoCycleEnabled="true"
                                app:sliderCircularHandlerEnabled="true"
                                app:sliderIndicatorAnimationDuration="600"
                                app:sliderIndicatorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                                app:sliderIndicatorMargin="15dp"
                                app:sliderIndicatorOrientation="horizontal"
                                app:sliderIndicatorPadding="3dp"
                                app:sliderIndicatorRadius="2dp"
                                app:sliderIndicatorSelectedColor="@color/white"
                                app:sliderIndicatorUnselectedColor="@color/white"
                                app:sliderScrollTimeInSec="1"
                                app:sliderStartAutoCycle="true" />
                        </RelativeLayout>





                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/AppointmentLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerViewSlider"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtAppointment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Laundry Appointment"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Appointmentlayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/AppointmentLinear"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="110dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/washandfold"
                                android:layout_width="140dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                android:src="@drawable/washandfold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/washandfoldtext"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text=" Wash &amp; Fold"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/AppointmentLinear1"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="109dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/AppointmentLinear"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/washandiron"
                                android:layout_width="140dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                android:src="@drawable/washandiron" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/washandirontxt"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Wash &amp; Iron"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/Appointmentlayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/AppointmentLinear2"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="110dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/steamironing"
                                android:layout_width="140dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                android:src="@drawable/steemironing" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/steamironingtxt"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text=" Steam Ironing"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/AppointmentLinear3"
                            android:layout_width="180dp"
                            android:layout_height="110dp"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/AppointmentLinear2"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_button"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/drycleaning"
                                android:layout_width="140dp"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                                android:src="@drawable/drycleaning" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/drycleaningtxt"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text=" Drycleaning"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/cat"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/AppointmentLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Categories"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewcategoryhome"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cat"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/category"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
```

enter code hereapp:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:reverseLayout="false">

```
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
 </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabwhatsapp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icons8whatsapp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabdirectorder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_shop"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:elevation="6dp"
                app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>


            <!--        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>-->
        </LinearLayout>

       <!-- <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />-->
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Adaptor layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryproducts_imageview"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/defaultimage"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryproducts_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Please Give me Solution

Comment: share more code like activity and layout file

Comment: Did you try to wait? Because you're getting this image online. Just run ur app and wait for like 30 seconds and let me know if it appears

Comment: i wait 1h but 1st time not show

Comment: i got the image url in adaptor